# Issue in receiving emails

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my project in mvc4 using c#. I have a contact page i my website. My need is that **i have to receive messages to my email id from other id's**,  when clicking the Send button.I use the following code

```
public void ReceiveMail(string name,string email,string message)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailId"));
    msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
    msg.Subject =name + "send a message";
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    msg.Body = message;
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");// i am confused what to write here
    SmtpServer.Send(msg);
}
```

It shows the error

```
 The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.
 The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 
 at4sm42219747pbc.30 - gsmtp
```

I don't know from which server i got the mail. Then how can i solve this issue . Please help me

Comment: You are missing network credentials

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails with Gmail requires some additional settings. At first, port number should be 587 (instead of default 25). At second, Gmail requires secure connection. And of course you should provide valid credentials.

All in all, initialization of SmtpClient should look like this:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

as the error says, a STARTTLS command should be used first. Thas means gmail only accepts mail via secure connection. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462628/the-server-response-was-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-i16sm1806350) enableSsl was set to true. As the [documentation from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says, the SmtpClient class has such an property too. Furthermore you should leave your credentials in the smptClient. I think gmail only accepts mail from authenticate users. I think the whole problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NetworkCredential` to login into Gmail SMTP server. Error is very apparent.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your-email", "your-password");
```

Comment: actually i want receive mails from other emails ..but using this i got the mail from my address

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpServer.Port = 587;
smtpServer.Credentials = 
    new NetworkCredential("SenderGmailUserName", "SenderPassword");
```

Comment: actually i want receive mails from other emails ..but using this i got the mail from my address

Comment: @Parvathiiiii Please take a look at my updated answer.The sender can send mail using his  credentials .You need to provide functionality to your user to provide there Username and Password (Not an recommended approach)

Comment: That is not sure sender always send from his gmail account, and also i have to receive mails, then how i know the senders password

Comment: well you can either make it mandatory to use gmail or you can use other smtp or even combine them in drop down list(like yahoo,AOL,etc..). You have to write seperate code for them.